# Compare two CSV Files with Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, csv, hash, compare

I have two CSV files that I want to compare with Perl.

I have the code to get the files into Perl using [`Text::CSV::Slurp`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV%3a%3aSlurp) and it gives me a nice array of hash references for the files.

Using [`Data::Dumper::Concise`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data%3a%3aDumper%3a%3aConcise) shows all my data imports correctly.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV::Slurp;
use Data::Dumper::Concise;

my $file1_src = "IPB-CSV.csv";

my $file2_src = "SRM-CSV.csv";

my $IPB = Text::CSV::Slurp->load(file => $file1_src);
my $SRM = Text::CSV::Slurp->load(file => $file2_src);

print Dumper($IPB);
print Dumper($SRM);
```

The results of the dump look something like this

**$IPB**

```
[
  {
    Drawing => "1001"
  },
  {
    Drawing => "1002"
  },
  {
    Drawing => "1003"
  }
]
```

**$SRM**

```
[
  {
    Drawing => "1001",
    Figure => "Figure 2-8",
    Index => 2,
    Nomenclature => "Some Part"
  },
  {
    Drawing => "1002",
    Figure => "Figure 2-8",
    Index => 2,
    Nomenclature => "Some Part"
  },
  {
    Drawing => "2001",
    Figure => "Figure 2-8",
    Index => 2,
    Nomenclature => "Some Part"
  },
  {
    Drawing => "2002",
    Figure => "Figure 2-8",
    Index => 2,
    Nomenclature => "Some Part"
  }
]
```

I want to compare the two arrays based on each hash's `Drawing` key, and create two CSV files as follows

- One containing the items that are in `$IPB` but not `$SRM`, containing only the data in the `Drawing column.
- Another where the item is in the `$SRM` but not the `$IPB`, containing all the fields that are related to the `Drawing` column.

I have found lots of information to compare files to see if they match, or to compare hashes or arrays for single pieces of data, but I can't find something specific to what I need.

Comment: Loop over each element in IPB, capture Drawing value, check if it exists in SRM, etc... After you've attempted some coding and still have problems, then post your code and ask a question. Good luck

Comment: `Text::CSV::Slurp` is a very big hammer that leaves you with data structures less than ideal for your task. Please can you show your two CSV data files?

Comment: I'd use [DBD::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3A%3ACSV) and SQL joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This short program uses your example values for `$ipb` and `$srm` and creates the output that I think you want. (*Please* don't use capital letters for anything but global identifiers like package names.)

There are a couple of problems

- Using [`Text::CSV::Slurp`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV%3a%3aSlurp) leaves you with two arrays of hashes that are no use for this task without further indexing. You would be much better off creating appropriate data structures from scratch by processing the file line-by-line
- You say that your second file must contain all of the information related to each `Drawing` key, but, because Perl hashes are inherently unordered, `Text::CSV::Slurp` has lost the order of the field names. The best that can be done is to print the data in whatever order it is found, but preceding it by a header line showing the field names. This is another reason for avoiding `Text::CSV::Slurp`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

# The original data

my $ipb = [{ Drawing => 1001 }, { Drawing => 1002 }, { Drawing => 1003 }];

my $srm = [
  {
    Drawing => "1001",
    Figure => "Figure 2-8",
    Index => 2,
    Nomenclature => "Some Part"
  },
  {
    Drawing => "1002",
    Figure => "Figure 2-8",
    Index => 2,
    Nomenclature => "Some Part"
  },
  {
    Drawing => "2001",
    Figure => "Figure 2-8",
    Index => 2,
    Nomenclature => "Some Part"
  },
  {
    Drawing => "2002",
    Figure => "Figure 2-8",
    Index => 2,
    Nomenclature => "Some Part"
  }
];

# Index the data

my %srm;
for my $item (@$srm) {
  my $drawing = $item->{Drawing};
  $srm{$drawing} = $item;
}

my %ipb;
for my $item (@$ipb) {
  my $drawing = $item->{Drawing};
  $ipb{$drawing} = 1;
}

# Create the output files

open my $csv1, '>', 'file1.csv';
for my $id (sort keys %ipb) {
  next if $srm{$id};
  print $csv1 $id, "\n";
}
close $csv1;

open my $csv2, '>', 'file2.csv';
my @keys = keys %{ $srm->[0] };
print $csv2 join(',', @keys), "\n";
for my $id (sort keys %srm) {
  next if $ipb{$id};
  print $csv2 join(',', @{$srm{$id}}{@keys}), "\n"; 
}
close $csv2;
```

**output**

**file1.csv**

```
1003
```

**file2.csv**

```
Drawing,Nomenclature,Index,Figure
2001,Some Part,2,Figure 2-8
2002,Some Part,2,Figure 2-8
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working great. This is only going to be used on my personal system to flag the data missing from either set so we can go back and look to see if we are missing something needed, or we are missing something that can be left out. If the fields (columns) are out of order from the way they went in, I'm ok. I can always move them around in excel if necessary.

Comment: I was using Text::CSV::Slurp because it was in another example, not because I wanted to hang onto it for any particular reason. This has been my first perl script in over 6 years. I used to be more familiar, but as it goes, if you don't use it you lose it I suppose. Thanks again for the assist.

Comment: Perl has changed a *lot* in six years! If you show your data then I will write something that will process it line-by-line to help you get back into it

Comment: So today I went to actually use the script, and I'm suddenly having issues. Since I originally posted this, I have re-formatted my PC. Installed and setup perl the same as I had before. However, now even when I run your exact code above to try and test things, my file2.csv is coming out out-of-order. And not just out of order as it had before (fields being mixed up) but the whole column is out of order. So all my data is jumbled and hard to even begin to sort it in excel. Any idea why things suddenly changed on me?

Comment: @SaskiFX: The contents of both `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` are sorted by drawing number. I guess you didn't notice before because there were so few records. What order do you want them in?

Comment: Running your exact code doesn't get me the same result anymore in file2.csv. Now I am getting:

`Index,Drawing,Figure,Nomenclature
Some Part,2001,Figure 2-8,2
Some Part,Figure 2-8,2002,2`

So my actual data in each row and column no longer match up. Every time I run it, I get a different file. I don't mind getting the columns out in random order so long as they are at least consistent. So I suppose you could say in any order. :)

Comment: @SaskiFX: Ah OK. I thought when you said *"the whole column is out of order"* that the order of the fields was fine but the rows were out of order. I guess you've upgraded to version 18 or later of Perl? [**The handling of hash keys changed in v18**](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.18.0/perldelta.html#Hash-overhaul) and it's now randomised. I've fixed it so that the fields in all the rows are in the same order, but it will still change from one run to the next. If you want that fixed as well you'll need to use `Text::CSV::Slurp` differently or even do away with it altogether. Let me know

Comment: Perfect! I knew something had to have changed since I had last installed Perl or I had changed something else in the modules I had loaded/installed, but the first seemed more likely. Thanks again!

Comment: @SaskiFX: So what is your new version of Perl 5?

Answer (score 1):

Since drawing is a criterion of sorts, why not "index" the data into something a little more convenient where the drawing index is the key and the corresponding data is a corresponding value?

```
my %ipb;
for my $record ( @$IPB ) {
    my $index = $record->{Drawing};
    push @{ $ipb{$index} }, $record;
}

my %srm;
for my $record ( @$SRM ) {
    my $index = $record->{Drawing};
    push @{ $srm{$index} }, $record;
}
```

Now it should be a breeze to figure out the indexes unique to `$IPB` and `$SRM`:

```
use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';
my @unique_ipb = uniq( grep { $ipb{$_} and not $srm{$_} } keys( %ipb ), keys( %srm ) );
my @unique_srm = uniq( grep { $srm{$_} and not $ipb{$_} } keys( %ipb ), keys( %srm ) );
```

What's common to both?

```
my @intersect = uniq( grep { $srm{$_} and $ipb{$_} } keys( %ipb ), keys( %srm ) );
```

What are all the figure number(s) for Drawing index 1002?

```
print $_->{Figure}, "\n" for @{ $ipb{1002} // [] }, @{ $srm{1002} // [] };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complicated, because your data structures are less than ideal for comparing. You have references to arrays of hash references, and you care about the data in one of the keys of the hashref. My first step would be to flatten IPB to an array (since there is no data under this), and convert SRM to a single hashref.

```
my @ipbarray = map { ${$_}{Drawing} } $IPB; # Creates an array from IPB.
my $srmhash = {};
for my $hash ($SRM) {
  ${$srmhash}{${$hash}{Drawing}} = $hash unless defined ${$srmhash}{${$hash}{Drawing}}; # Don't overwrite if it exists
}
```

Now we have 2 more workable data structures.

Next step is to contrast these values:

```
my @ipbonly = ();
my @srmonly = ();

for my $ipbitem (@ipbarray) {
  push @ipbonly, ( Drawing => $ipbitem } unless defined ${$srmhash}{$ipbtem};
}

for my $srmitem (keys $srmhash) {
  push @srmonly, ${$srmhash}{$srmitem} unless grep { $_ == $srmitem } @ipbarray;
}
```

At this point, @ipbonly and @srmonly will contain the data you want.

Comment: I think `for my $hash ($SRM)` needs to be `for my $hash (@$SRM)` here -  or maybe, to be consistent with [PBP](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0596001738) and [perlcritic](http://perl-critic.stacka.to/), something like `for my $hash (@{$SRM})`.

Comment: I believe later versions of perl can just iterate over the arrayref without explicitly referencing. But yes, both of these would also work, and probably be more backwards compatible.